# Unable to start an NSTrackingArea

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstrackingarea

I have an `NSOutlineView` that I'd ike to have `mouseEntered:` and `mouseExited:` updates during drag and drop. So I've tried to add an `NSTrackingArea` to it. Within my outline view sub-class I have:

```
let target = self.frame
let options = [NSTrackingAreaOptions.enabledDuringMouseDrag]
let area = NSTrackingArea(rect: target, options: options, owner: self, userInfo: nil)
self.addTrackingArea(area)
```

But I seem to get the runtime exception:

```
[General] trackingArea options 0x400 do not include a type
```

It must be something really obvious but all the Google results don't seem to indicate what I'm doing wrong. If I do:

```
var trackingID = self.addTrackingRect(target, owner: self, userData: nil, assumeInside: false)
```

then the mouse methods do fire but obviously only when the mouse button is released.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstrackingareaoptions):

> **NSTrackingAreaOptions**
>
> The data type defined for the constants specified in the options parameter of `init(rect:options:owner:userInfo:)`. These constants are described below; you can specify multiple constants by performing a bitwise-OR operation with them. **In particular, you must supply one or more of the tracking-type constants** (that is, `mouseEnteredAndExited`, `mouseMoved`, and `cursorUpdate`) **and one of the active constants** (that is, `activeWhenFirstResponder`, `activeInKeyWindow`, `activeInActiveApp`, and `activeAlways`). **In addition, you may specify any of the behavior constants** (that is, `assumeInside`, `inVisibleRect`, and `enabledDuringMouseDrag`).

That means one or more of the `type` constants and one of the `active` constants are required.